# Wpf Placing Object

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i'm trying to make an application that allows me to create objects and place them in a canvas area. The actual behave of my application is:

1. Create an object and add it to a listbox
2. You can modify the object by rightclicking it on the listbox and also duplicate it
3. To place the object in the canvas area drag and drop it from the list box
4. You can move freely the object in the area by dragging and dropping it

My question is how should I handle if an item is already placed in that area?
I already check that but only for

```
Private Sub MyCanvas_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim Position As Point = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas)
End Sub
```

With that i check if the left button is released over an used area but if I release the mouse before the object will overlap the other one

Also i would like to define a grid to dispose the objects in a well-ordered way thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

trye something like this:

```
<Canvas     >
<ScrollViewer   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  AllowDrop="True" >

                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <yourControls/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
</Canvas>
```

This will self-organize your controls, or anything else you include there